# convert string to ASCII c++

Tags: visual-c++

I am trying to get the program to read 2 string then convert them to ASCII value and compare the 2 value.

I am not sure how to change the string to ASCII value for the comparing function to work.

```
#include <iostream>


int main()
{

    char ch[50];
    std::cout << "Enter a character: ";
    std::cin.getline(ch, sizeof(ch));
    std::cout << "ASCII Value of " << ch << " is " << int(ch) << std::endl;

    char cha[50];
    std::cout << "Enter a character: ";
    std::cin >> cha;
    std::cout << "ASCII Value of " << cha << " is " << int(cha) << std::endl;

    if (ch[50] == cha[50]) {
        std::cout << "ASCII Value of " << cha << " is " << "equal to " << ch;
        return 0;
    }

    else if (ch > cha) {
        std::cout << ch << " is greater than " << cha << std::endl;
        std::cout << int(ch) - int(cha) << "is the differents between the two " ;
        return 1;
    }
    else

    {
        std::cout << ch << " is less than " << cha;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String to ASCII conversion C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40019889/string-to-ascii-conversion-c)

Comment: You should get used to using `std::string` instead of `char[]` when working with strings in C++. After all, what's the point of using an object oriented language if you're not using the tools it has to offer?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> char ch[50];
> std::cout << "Enter a character: ";
> std::cin.getline(ch, sizeof(ch));
> ```

`char ch[50]` is *"array of character"* otherwise known as *"string"*

> ```
> if (ch[50] == cha[50]) { ... }
> ```

Both `ch` and `ch50` have 50 elements. The index starts at zero, that means the last valid element is `ch[49]`. `ch[50]` is buffer overflow and causes undefined behavior.

You want instead to declare a single character, `char ch;` and read that character. Or declare `ch[50]` and read the string, and do a comparison for `ch[0]` (that's the first element in the index)

```
int main()
{
    char ch;
    char cha;

    std::cout << "Enter one character: ";
    std::cin >> ch;
    std::cout << "ASCII Value of " << ch << " is " << int(ch) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Enter a character: ";
    std::cin >> cha;
    std::cout << "ASCII Value of " << cha << " is " << int(cha) << std::endl;

    if(ch == cha) 
    {
        std::cout << "ASCII Value of " << cha << " is " << "equal to " << ch;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << ch << " is greater than " << cha << std::endl;
        if(ch > cha)
            std::cout << ch << " is greater than " << cha << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << ch << " is less than " << cha;
    }

    return 0;
}
```